# angular ui-select: calling a function with one of the items selected

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I have a ui-select element with:

```
<ui-select-match style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Select values...">{{$item["name"]}}</ui-select-match>
```

I want to call a function when user clicks on any one of the selected item(there can be multiple items selected). So the invoked function would only receive the item clicked.

```
<ui-select-match ng-click="$ctrl.myFunction($item["name"])" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Select values...">{{$item["name"]}}</ui-select-match>
```

But it is not working. myFunction receives undefined value.
What is correct way of getting hold of selected item?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you watch the value of the model that gets updated

```
<ui-select ng-model="model.example">
```

in Js

```
$scope.$watch('model.example', function () {...});
```